# Getting error OWIN start.cs while web API hosting on prem IIS server and api having azure ad bearer authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, asp.net-web-api2, owin-middleware, owin-security

I have implemented azure ad authentication in SPA app and validating the token using OWIN start.cs. it is working fine in local environment. below code used for token validation:

```
    app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Tenant = tenant,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            //ValidAudiences = new[] { Audience },
            ValidAudience = validateAudience,
            ValidateIssuer = false,
            ValidIssuers = new[] { ValidIssuers }
        }
    });
```

when I deployed this published code on prem server and run web api it throws error as mentioned in below screen shot. I have used Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory version 4.2.2.0,  [image][image]

can anyone help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error   ***`task was canceled`*** is expected when an HTTP request is canceled maybe  `if the user closes the page suddenly.` or cancels before execution completes.

The TaskCanceledException is mostly timeout.But to check the exception, it may have to be inspected with try catch.

```
try
{
    var response = task.Result;
}
catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
{
    // Check ex.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested here.
    // If false, we may assume it was a timeout in most cases.
}
```

you can try to suppress response if the cancellation token occurred by using    `if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)`

```
 HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
        }
        return response;
```

If it is due to time out ,it can be set to some value.Plesae check the references.

```
var clientHttp = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)
```

In some cases of use , `await` can be used for simultaneous tasks to be completed with async.

**References:**

1. [c# - "Task was canceled" errors on Azure website - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23298421/task-was-canceled-errors-on-azure-website)
2. [c# - HttpClient - A task was cancelled? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29179848/httpclient-a-task-was-cancelled#:%7E:text=There%27s%202%20likely%20reasons%20that%20a%20TaskCanceledException%20would,complete%20within%20the%20timespan%20you%20specified%20on%20HttpClient.Timeout.)

Comment: Thanks for replying kavyasaraboju-MT, it was issue with IIS, I disabled impersonate in IIS, it fixed my issue.