# Performing a server-side call using async/await pattern (error: TaskCanceledException)

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm performing an AJAX call to my Web API, using the technology WebAPI.

The method that handles that request is the following:

```cs
[Route("RenderNotificationsPopup")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> RenderNotificationsPopup(bool responsive = false)
{
    return await GetContentAsync(string.Format("RenderNotificationsPopup?responsive={0}", responsive ? 1 : 0));
}
```

This method calls `GetContentAsync` which peforms a server-side call using the class `HttpClient`.

```cs
private async Task<string> GetContentAsync(string urlSuffix)
{
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await client.GetStringAsync(string.Format(
                "{0}/Header/{1}",
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GatewaysHttpRoot"],
                urlSuffix));
        }
}
```

Everything is working fine, except when users close the page while the AJAX query is pending a response from WebApi. In that case, I get this error:

> Message: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was
> canceled.
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
> at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()

I can reproduce this issue myself by loading the page and closing it before I get the response of the AJAX query, like if leaving the page before while WebApi is processing the query is struggling itself.

I searched on the Web and saw that there is a bug related to that ([ASP.NET Web API OperationCanceledException when browser cancels the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157596/asp-net-web-api-operationcanceledexception-when-browser-cancels-the-request)). Despite that, it apparently concerns an old version of WebApi package and I'm using the latest version.

Did I do a mistake in my code about the async/await pattern or is it always that nasty bug ?

Many thanks !

**EDIT**: I tried the workaround given in the SO post I linked (using the class `CancelledTaskBugWorkaroundMessageHandler`) and I still get the TaskCanceledException.

**EDIT 2**: Seems that this issue cannot be avoided. Is it possible to handle such exceptions in WebApi applications ?

Comment: what is your problem with the exception? Does your appication crush? Behavior is normal I think, cause why should the task continue work when the client is gone.

Comment: I'm wondering if getting an exception is normal, because an exception is usually synonym of error. Also, I'm wondering if I can catch it properly in order to avoid to have hundred of them per days in the server logs.

Comment: Where do you get this exception? As the HTTP response? Or in the debugger?

Comment: I added an answer that enables me to properly handle this exception finally. This one also answers to your question. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use my own derived class of **ExceptionFilterAttribute** in order to log the exception related to the WebApi application, overriding the method `OnException`.

The proper way I found to handle the exception **TaskCanceledException** is to override `OnExceptionAsync` instead of `OnException` and rely on the property `IsCancellationRequested` to detect when the task is canceled.

Here is the method I use as error handling:

```
public override async Task OnExceptionAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    if (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        //Handle domain specific exceptions here if any.

        //Handle all other Web Api (not all, but Web API specific only ) exceptions
        Logger.Write(context.Exception, "Email");

        context.Response = context.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An unhandled exception was thrown.");
    }
}
```

Where the class **Logger** comes from the Enterprise Library Application Blocks.

Comment: This is the bees knees, I had issues with `IExceptionHandler` not catching `TaskCancelledException` in Web API 2, this example solves that. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

It is normal for the task to be canceled, if the underlying client connection is dead. You need to handle the exception.

Comment: Okay, so what is the best practices to handle such cases ? I didn't read anything related to that behavior on the documentation of Microsoft. I tested the workaround of the SO post linked in my question in order to handle the exception but I'm still encountering it.

Comment: This exception seems to come from MVC internal code.