# Asp.net WebAPI HTTP SERVER ERRORS - user breaks the connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web.Api project, and I deployed it to Azure Web Sites.
Some times I see many **HTTP SERVER ERRORS** in dashboard.

> Detailed Error Information: Module    ManagedPipelineHandler
>   Notification  ExecuteRequestHandler
>   Handler   System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler Error
>   Code  0x800703e3 Requested
>   URL   http://test-server:80/api/Statistics/ShowStories Physical
>   Path  D:\home\site\wwwroot\api\Statistics\ShowStories Logon
>   Method    Anonymous Logon User    Anonymous

I don't know how to fix it and why it happens.

**UPDATE**

I found what this happens because user breaks the internet connections, and my question in next: how to catch this problems, maybe create some custom exception handler, and logger this problems, what this 'http server errors' and not show to Azure dashboard?

Comment: Did you try enabling [ASP.NET Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973(v=vs.100).aspx) to see if any helpful details are logged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: [ASP.NET Web API OperationCanceledException when browser cancels the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157596/asp-net-web-api-operationcanceledexception-when-browser-cancels-the-request)

I think that if you handle OperationCanceledException correctly, the error will not be logged.

Comment: I'm handling `OperationCanceledException` in a quite robust way, and I still see these errors once in a while. So I have a feeling that this is not the correct answer.