# ASP.NET Web API OperationCanceledException - Preventing error 500 to be written to iis log

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have encountered the same problem and used the solution which were presented here:
["ASP.NET Web API OperationCanceledException when browser cancels the request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157596/asp-net-web-api-operationcanceledexception-when-browser-cancels-the-request)
. 
This works great but I still have an issue with error 500 which appears in the iis logs:

> 2016-05-01 13:46:31 ::1 POST /obo.Con.Web/1.0/config at=MDAxMDAxAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAApV8goVQlvq2eNe0QKvXnHtHf4eFnGIptk0NNHyq8u3KBLSFfcU4D%2fb06yfU8X%2bUONdZYbRMVkC02UMoYCa56HLNEEZC2AzHrcYJm2eCswJOTpn1oYZRmBeY%3d&ct=iOS&cst=iPad&sv=2.2.0.64&cv=2.2.0.64 80 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/49.0.2623.112+Safari/537.36 **500** 0 64 1088

The problem is that our system identify this as an error.
Is there a way to prevent this log from being written or maybe manipulate it in some way so it could be distinguish from a "real" 500 error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Global.asax Application_Error I added this code:

```
 protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (Server.GetLastError() is OperationCanceledException)
     {
         Response.Clear();
         Server.ClearError();
      }
 }
```

This clears the last exception and error 500 is not being written to iis log