# What happens when an XMLHttpRequest is aborted?

Tags: javascript, http, browser, xmlhttprequest, abort

- Will an aborted `XMLHttpRequest` still download the response from the server?
- At what point in the request lifecycle does it differ from a regular request?
- Do different browsers behave differently?
- Is it bad practise to abort requests?

Comment: some of your questions are answered in ["documentation"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort) - and the ["specification"](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-abort()-method)

Answer (score 2):

- No, the download will (should) cancel (does in my browser at least)
- > When a request is aborted, its readyState is changed to XMLHttpRequest.UNSENT (0) and the request's status code is set to 0. -- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort)
- No, at least hopefully not. They *should* be following [the spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-abort()-method).
- In my opinion, definitely not. It's a waste of bandwidth and other resources to have requests you no longer need running in the background. Much better to abort them.

**Two recent use-cases from personal experience:**

- A table with various parameters for filtering. Depending on the parameters selected, the resulting request sometimes took a while to complete. If you selected a slow set of parameters A, and then a fast set of parameters B before A completed, you'd first see the results of B in the table, but then A would eventually complete and "replace" the contents of the table so you'd suddenly see A instead.
  **Solution:** Abort the previous incomplete request before starting the next one.
- SPA with pages with sometimes long running requests, for example the previously mentioned table. When navigating away to a different page, there were sometimes several requests running in the background for stuff no longer needed.
  **Solution:** Register those requests to be aborted when the page/component was unmounted.

Comment: When aborting a request from client side, is the server informed ? I tend to think it is the case from  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621596/607162), but I can't found precise information.