# Xamarin Async deadlock - Cannot get data from API

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to connect to an API and get the data from the "User" table so that the credentials can be authenticated. However after executing `GetAsync()` the app sticks in a deadlock and doesn't do anything. I have tested the API with postman and it works.

```
public async Task<User> UserCredentialsGet(string name, string password)
    {
        var user = new User();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        string url = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/Users/username=" + name + "/" + "password=" + password ;
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);
        try
        {
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(content);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }

        return user;
        //return await Task.FromResult(user);
    }
```

Comment: is it actually deadlocked, or is it just hung?  Are you your request is completing?  Have you tried without using `ConfigureAwait`?

Comment: Why are you not using await here?  `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result`  You should almost 100% always avoid using `.Result` as it can lead to deadlocks.  You should use `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` instead.

Comment: +1 for Kirks comment. Also because you said your code hangs on the `GetAsync()` call, try specifying the client timeout manually to a lower value to see if you really get an answer from the API and it isn't just a timeout (default is 100 seconds).
Example: `client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);`

Comment: Yes I have tried without `ConfigureAwait` but nothing happens. I have also tried without `.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` but again the result is the same. The problem is in `var response = await client.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);` line anyway.

Comment: @DannyBoy i used timeout but what changed is that now i get the error message _System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'_ a lot faster.

Comment: have you tested connectivity from your device's browser?

Comment: @Jason Yes the api works fine. I tested it from both the PC's browser and my phone's.

Comment: Have you tested the exact URI that the httpClient calls though? There might be a difference between the one you called and the httpClient.
`string url = "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/api/Users/username=" + name + "/" + "password=" + password ;
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);`

Comment: @DannyBoy I checked the url value by adding a breakpoint and it is the same address I use with postman and browser.

Comment: Hope this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22157596/asp-net-web-api-operationcanceledexception-when-browser-cancels-the-request can give u some insights.

Answer (score 0):

GetAsync is Idisposable so try to use something like

```
    `using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {   
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken))
            {
                var stringResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                //todo process response
            }
        }
`
```

For me it works fine.
Do not for forget *await* response

Comment: Thank you but it didnt work unfortunately. Its hanging at [using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri, cancellationToken))].
After a while I get an error: System.OperationCanceledException: 'The operation was canceled.'

Comment: System.OperationCanceledException is fired by cancelation token or timeout.

Comment: Are you sure that you are hiting a corect endpoint? Do you have correct url? 
something like 
 `/username?=" + name`
Maby missing questionmark

Comment: I tried this with and without cancellation token. The api is running locally on debug mode and i changed the address from "localhost" to the internal ip. As I mentioned it runs well with postman and swagger so I cannot see a problem with the endpoint.

Comment: Ou sorry, i did not catch that, if your API is running on localhost you have to set a binding configuration in IISExpress  in .vs\config\applicationhost.config  
something like this
 https://www.arkleseizure.net/accessing-a-local-net-website-api-from-a-xamarin-app

Comment: I didnt find the file that was specified in the guide because i dont use IIS Express. However I edited the `applicationUrl` setting in `launchsettings.json` with zero results. I was hopeful for a moment when the guide mentioned that the android client cannot connect to the api while the connection settings are binded to localhost, but the miracle didnt happen...